# Replace a single line pattern by multiple lines in python using sed

Tags: python, sed

This is in test.txt

`swift-ring-builder account.builder add zZONE-STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/DEVICE 100`

I want to replace above line with multiple lines in python using sed, so that the above line becomes:

```
swift-ring-builder account.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6002/sda 100
swift-ring-builder container.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6001/sda 100
swift-ring-builder object.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6000/sda 100
```

I used:

```
import subprocess

def search_and_replace_pattern(oldstr, newstr, path):
    subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', 's#'+oldstr+'#'+newstr+'#', path])
```

But then i get :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 88: unterminated `s' command
```

In the subprocess I used `#` because my pattern containes `/`, so I used the `#` delimiter so that sed does not confuse with `/`

Please suggest a solution using `subprocess` or any other way like `os.system(cmd)`

Comment: Why not use the `re` module in Python instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hi Martijn, I am new to this, can you please specify how to use `re` module

Comment: It is far from clear to me how your input would lead to your output. You did not include your `oldstr` and `newstr` values.

Comment: `oldstr = swift-ring-builder account.builder add zZONE-STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/DEVICE 100` and newstr is the above 3 multiple lines

Comment: Right, in that case you don't even need to use regular expressions; just rewrite the file with the matching line replaced by the 3 new lines. I've written up an answer that does just that below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `sed`; use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to replace lines in your file instead:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    if line.strip() == 'swift-ring-builder account.builder add zZONE-STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/DEVICE 100':
        sys.stdout.write(
            'swift-ring-builder account.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6002/sda 100\n'
            'swift-ring-builder container.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6001/sda 100\n'
            'swift-ring-builder object.builder add z1-10.0.0.2:6000/sda 100\n'
        )
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This loops over the file named by `filename`, re-writing each line as it was originally, unless the line is equal to `'swift-ring-builder account.builder add zZONE-STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/DEVICE 100'`, in which case three different lines are written.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the line in question in the `oldstr` using regular expression:

```
pattern = r'^(swift-ring-builder )account(.builder add )zZONE-STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/DEVICE 100$'
replacement = '\\g<1>account\\g<2>z1-10.0.0.2:6002/sda 100\n' \ 
              '\\g<1>container\\g<2>z1-10.0.0.2:6001/sda 100\n' \
              '\\g<1>object\\g<2>z1-10.0.0.2:6000/sda 100\n'
newstr = re.sub(pattern, replacement, oldstr)
```

Have a look at [re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

**Edit.** But for this simple task i would personally prefer the method of Martijn Pieters.

Comment: This produces just **one** line; the OP wants to replace 1 line by 3 different lines, with literal text.